# Apache tomcat server local host url

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, server

when i run my application using tomcat server in eclipse i will be redirected to following URL: `"HTTP://localhost:8080/example/login"` .

`/login` is my controller request mapping , but `example` is also getting appended. How can I remove that from my URL.

the following is my server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>
    <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

    <GlobalNamingResources>
        <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
    </GlobalNamingResources>

    <Service name="Catalina">

        <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
        <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>


        <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">

            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
                <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
            </Realm>

            <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">

                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"/>

                <Context docBase="sourcelead" path="/sourcelead" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:sourcelead"/><Context docBase="spring-mvc" path="/spring-mvc" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:spring-mvc"/></Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your project settings in Eclipse.

Right click on your project

-Properties

-Web Project Settings

-Change your context path

And finally clean and rebuild your project.